# Grid floor is not straight

Tags: interface, 3d-view

My grid is askew and I don't know why

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have rotated the view with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MW] Scroll</kbd>.

To re-align it, try going into an aligned view (e.g. *Front view* with <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>).